# python - ImportError: cannot import name wsgiserver

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, cherrypy, cherrypywsgiserver

Getting following error when running python script for web

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "SampleWSTest.py", line 10, in <module>
        from web.wsgiserver.ssl_builtin import BuiltinSSLAdapter
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\wsgiserver\ssl_builtin.py", line 14, in <module>
        from cherrypy import wsgiserver
    ImportError: cannot import name wsgiserver
```

Running on python 2.7.15

```
import web
import sys
import argparse
import traceback
from web.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer
from web.wsgiserver.ssl_builtin import BuiltinSSLAdapter
from OpenSSL import SSL

class Healthcheck:
    def GET(self):
        return 'Yassssssssss !!!!!'

URLS = ('/svc/healthcheck', 'Healthcheck')

CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_certificate = 'alice.crt'
CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_private_key = 'alice.key'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_adapter = BuiltinSSLAdapter(CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_certificate, CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_private_key)
    CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_adapter.context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
    CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_adapter.context.set_options(SSL.OP_NO_SSLv3)
    CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_adapter.context.use_certificate_file(CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_certificate)
    CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_adapter.context.use_privatekey_file(CherryPyWSGIServer.ssl_private_key)
    app = web.application(URLS, globals())
    app.run()
```

This started failing after we had to disable `ssl 2` and `ssl 3` so had to add `ssl_adapter` but BuiltinSSLAdapter fails with the import.
If any other alternatives please suggest. Basically want to disable `ssl 2` and `ssl 3` previously we didnt have  `from web.wsgiserver.ssl_builtin import BuiltinSSLAdapter`
`from OpenSSL import SSL`

Comment: what's this "web" package ? And what do you get if you execute this  "import cherrypy; print(cherrypy)" ?

Comment: it prints - `<module 'cherrypy' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\__init__.pyc'>`

Comment: Did you also install cheroot, as CherryPy moved the webserver to Cheroot project?

Answer (score 4):

CherryPy moved wsgiserver to cheroot in 2017.

http://docs.cherrypy.dev/en/latest/history.html#v9-0-0

So now you need to import it like this:

```
from cheroot.wsgi import Server as CherryPyWSGIServer
```

or rename it throughout.

Comment: This didnt help - script runs but i dont get any response. get - `localhost sent an invalid response.`

Comment: Also need to change `from web.wsgiserver.ssl_builtin import BuiltinSSLAdapter` to `from web.wsgiserver.ssl.builtin import BuiltinSSLAdapter`